# How to set the maximum sash moves

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi i've a code that look like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import socket, time, datetime


class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Chating App")
        self.root.geometry("500x500")

    def widgets(self):
        self.m1 = PanedWindow(self.root, sashrelief=RAISED, width=10)
        self.m1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.main_frame_1 = Frame(self.m1)
        self.m1.add(self.main_frame_1)
        
        Label(self.main_frame_1, text="hello worlds").pack()


        self.m2 = PanedWindow(self.m1, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.m1.add(self.m2)
        self.label2 = Label(self.m2, text="top")
        self.m2.add(self.label2)


    def run(self):
        self.widgets()
        mainloop()

UI().run()
```

and my question is how can i set the maximum distances of the sash to be dragged?, so the user can drag the sash without fully shrinking the other pane. sorry if i misspelling :)

Comment: `self.m1.add(..., minsize=100)`. Documentation: [PanedWindow](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/pane-options.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add item to `PanedWindow` then you can set its minimal size

```
self.m1.add(..., minsize=100)
```

If you use `horizontal` orientation then it will be used as minimal `width`.

If you use `vertical` orientation then it will be used as minimal `height`.

---

Documentation: [PanedWindow](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/pane-options.html)

---

Working code:

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk

class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Chating App")
        self.root.geometry("500x500")

    def widgets(self):
        self.m1 = tk.PanedWindow(self.root, width=10, sashrelief='raised')
        self.m1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        
        self.main_frame_1 = tk.Frame(self.m1)
        self.m1.add(self.main_frame_1, minsize=100)
        
        self.label_hello = tk.Label(self.main_frame_1, text="hello worlds")
        self.label_hello.pack()

        self.m2 = tk.PanedWindow(self.m1, orient='vertical', sashrelief='raised')
        self.m1.add(self.m2, minsize=100)
        
        self.label_top = tk.Label(self.m2, text="top")
        self.m2.add(self.label_top, minsize=100)

        self.label_bottom = tk.Label(self.m2, text="bottom")
        self.m2.add(self.label_bottom, minsize=100)

    def run(self):
        self.widgets()
        self.root.mainloop()

UI().run()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pp-0008/)

Comment: Thanks, it's running like i expect :)